# why doesn't scrollY for href go to my desired position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm trying to link to a div within a page and I'm asking `window.scrollTo(0, $(this.hash));` to go to the location where the div is located.

When I console.log it, it is correct but when I use it in window.scrollTo it goes to the top of the page. Why would it not go to the correct location?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.hash);
        console.log(e.currentTarget.href.indexOf('#'));
        console.log($(this.hash));
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);
        console.log(window.location.hash);
        if(e.currentTarget.href.indexOf('#') != -1){
            // console.log(window.location);
            window.scrollTo(0, $(this.hash)); //the scrollY should be the hash location
            console.log($(this.hash));
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you see in `console.log($(this.hash));`?

Comment: `window.scrollTo()` method doesn't accept a jq object as parameter. Maybe you are confusing with this plugin https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: Since you are using jquery, why don't you use jquery for scroll it too? as simple as `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 100}, 200);`

Comment: Use `$(this.hash).offset().top` in the `scrollTo()` call

Comment: @ShaunakD. I see: [div#correctDIV, context: document, selector: "#correctDIV"]

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I swear I tried that and it didn't work...but I tried it again and now it does...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `window.scrollTo` does. You can find the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

It basically accepts an xPos and yPos as arguments. Therefore, you could do something like `window.scrollTo(0, $(this.hash).offset().top)` or you could do a `$(window).animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top})`

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: you mean $(this).offset() instead of $(this.hash).offset() ?

Comment: No. `$(this).offset()` gives you the offset of the button, not the element you want to scroll to.

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff I missed that one